# How to get TextField to render in API Browser in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using DRF, I have a User model that includes an Address field, which is a TextField.  When I view the UserList endpoint in the API Browser, Address looks like this:

```
"address": "<django.db.models.fields.TextField>",
```

From the documentation, I thought I needed this in my serializer:

```py
    address = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'},
    )
```

...but that didn't fix the problem.  The same thing is happening with PhoneNumberField type fields:

```
"phone_number": "<phonenumber_field.modelfields.PhoneNumberField>",
```

I redefined them in my serializer as CharField.

UPDATE:

My models and serializers are a bit more complex than usual because I'm splitting the Address, Country, and three phone fields out into separate classes so they can be included in several different models.

My User models:

```py
class User(AbstractUser, AddressPhoneModelMixin):
    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    timezone = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
    )
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
```

This is the model class for Address and Phone fields:

```py
class AddressPhoneModelMixin(object):
    address = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    fax_number = PhoneNumberField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

The User serializer:

```py
class UserSerializer(AddressPhoneSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="users:user-detail")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'type',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'full_name',
            'email',
            'address',
            'country',
            'phone_number',
            'mobile_number',
            'fax_number',
            'is_superuser',
            'is_staff',
            'is_active',
            'is_verified',
            'date_joined',
            'last_login',
        )
```

The Address and Phone fields serializer:

```py
class AddressPhoneSerializerMixin(serializers.Serializer):

    address = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=1000,
        style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'},
    )
    country = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='countries:country-detail'
    )
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=31,
    )
    mobile_number = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=31,
    )
    fax_number = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=31,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And, finally, the User views:

```py
class UserList(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserDetail(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

I'll include an example from the API Browser that includes all of the fields in question.  Note that Country shows as expected.

```
"email": "admin@virticl.api",
"address": "<django.db.models.fields.TextField>",
"country": "http://virticl.api/countries/1/",
"phone_number": "<phonenumber_field.modelfields.PhoneNumberField>",
"mobile_number": "<phonenumber_field.modelfields.PhoneNumberField>",
"fax_number": "<phonenumber_field.modelfields.PhoneNumberField>",
```

Comment: can you add your views as well as serializer?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your abstract model mixin should be a `models.Model` subclass:

```
class AddressPhoneModelMixin(models.Model):
    ...
```

You'll also need to put it to the left in the order of base classes for your user model as inheritance is processed from right to left:

```
class User(AddressPhoneModelMixin, AbstractUser):
    ...
```

NOTE: to [specify serializer fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include), you can use `fields = '__all__'` instead of listing them individually.  If there are just one or two missing, you can use `exclude` instead.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you.

Re: using "__all__" for fields, it's not a matter of needing to exclude any fields, but rather adding one.  If I specify "__all__", how would I add the "url" hyperlinked field, which is not an actual database field?

Comment: `__all__` doesn't refer to database fields.  It refers to serializer fields.  The `ModelSerializer` maps model fields to serializer fields, but that just means that your serializer fields are then all of your model fields plus whatever you define explicitly in the serializer.

Comment: As a side note: I just noticed you defined `permission_classes` on your Serializer, but that's a view attribute.  I don't think it has any effect in a serializer (unless you're making use of it somewhere yourself).